# Script to list all dwg files and convert them to geodatabase

Tags: python-2.7

This script is an improvement on the previously posted one but it is
still giving me an error of "Failed to execute (CADToGeodatabase)"
It is able to iterate through the directories and subdirectories, list
the dwg files, create the geodatabase but not able to populate it with
the feature datasets and feature classes due to the error!. Please help!

```
import os, os.path, arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "J:/2010"
# Set workspace and variables
gdb = r"C:\data\2010.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
# Create a FileGDB for the fds
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/data", "2010.gdb")
reference_scale = "1500"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("J:/2010/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.dwg'):
           print "current file is: " + file
           outDS = arcpy.ValidateTableName(os.path.splitext("d" +  
           os.path.basename(file))[0])
           arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(file, gdb, outDS, reference_scale)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line saying `def recursive_file_gen(r"J:\2010"):` looks strange to me. I don't think you can put a literal string there. I am surprised that this runs at all. Maybe you meant to do something like `def recursive_file_gen(directory=r"J:\2010"):` or simply `def recursive_file_gen():`.

Also, I think the line saying `yield os.path.join(root, file)` needs to be indented more to be considered inside of the inner for loop.

I don't see specifically what is causing the script to work only in one subdirectory. I will need more details about what is happening.

**EDIT:** I didn't notice that the `recursive_file_gen` function is not being used at all. I don't know what is causing the problem. I think someone who is more familiar with arcpy would be more helpful to you.